# Keychain upgrade apps Xcode 6.1.1 to 8.3.3

Tags: ios, keychain

We have 6 apps built with Xcode 6.1.1 published on the App Store and we need to upgrade them to Xcode 8.3.3.

Upon publishing the first app built with XCode 8.3.3, we found out that users that had the previous version (built with XCode 6.1.1) lost all data saved in the Keychain.

We checked the two artifacts generated by our builds and in the mobileprovision used with XCode6.1.1 and Xcode 8.3.3 have the same lines for ApplicationIdentifierPrefix and keychain-access-groups.

We noticed that the app generated with Xcode 8.3.3, when trying to read the Keychain the first time, returns a “-25300” code (errSecItemNotFound)

This problem seems to occur only with devices that have a version  of iOS greater than 8.3. (We tested on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3 and it worked correctly).

Can you help us address this issue? Is there anything we can do?

Comment: I would contact Apple and use one of your `TSI`s that come with your Developer membership: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/ . It is unlikely that Stack Overflow can assist you without an MCVE; how do you expect anyone to understand what is happening in your app?

Comment: maybe someone had a similar problem with the keychain by upgrading from Xcode 6 to Xcode 8 ...

Comment: I think you mean iOS rather than Xcode. Xcode is just the development environment and has nothing to do with the Keychain API and behaviour on a device. If you create an MCVE and raise a TSI then Apple will be able inform you about if this is a change in API behaviour or a bug in your code. You should also review the iOS Release Notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8_3.html

Comment: No, I mean my artifacts. If they are generated with Xcode 8 they have this problem.If I create artifacts with Xcode 6 I have not problems. Where I work, we create ipa through Jenkins. If I try to generate 1 with Xcode 6 and upgrade with Xcode 8 I encounter this problem.